# the_content filter on some post types only not working

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, the-content

I'm using a filter on the_content to insert an ad after the first paragraph of a post and it is working fine. But I'm also using a plugin called Live Blogging Plus and it uses a post type called liveblog_entry. I don't want the ad to appear in every liveblog entry. Conditional tags are somehow not working. I've tried is_singular('liveblog_entry'). Maybe it is because the entries are being pulled into a regular post with a shortcode and conditional tags are detecting only the parent posts' attributes?

Comment: `if ( in_the_loop() ) {}`